# Im trying to pull a random word from a file for a hang man project and its giving me this error

Tags: python

```
import random

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "C:/Users/14237/Downloads/softwear/words.txt"

def loadWords():
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = line.split()
    print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
    return wordlist

def chooseWord(wordlist):
    return random.choice(wordlist)

--------------------------------------
def hangman(secretWord):
    guesses = 8
    lettersGuessed = []
    print("Welcome to the game, Hangman!")
    print("I am thinking of a word that is", str(len(secretWord)), "letters long.")
    while True:
        print("-------------")
        print("You have", guesses, "guesses left.")
        print("Available letters:", getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))
        userGuess = input("Please guess a letter: ")
        userGuess = userGuess.lower()
    if userGuess in lettersGuessed:
        print("Oops! You've already guessed that letter:", getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
    elif userGuess in secretWord:        
        lettersGuessed.append(userGuess)
        print("That is correct!:", getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
    else:
        guesses -= 1
        lettersGuessed.append(userGuess)
        print("Sorry, that letter was not correct:", getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
    if guesses == 0:
        print("-------------")
        print("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was", secretWord + ".")
    elif isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed) == True:
        print("------------")
        print("Congratulations, you won!")
secretWord = chooseWord(wordlist)
hangman(secretWord)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [74], in <cell line: 27>()
         25         print("------------")
         26         print("Congratulations, you won!")
    ---> 27 secretWord = chooseWord(wordlist)
         28 hangman(secretWord)
    
    Input In [68], in chooseWord(wordlist)
         16 def chooseWord(wordlist):
    ---> 17     return random.choice(wordlist)
    
    File ~\anaconda3\lib\random.py:346, in Random.choice(self, seq)
        344 """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
        345 # raises IndexError if seq is empty
    --> 346 return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
    
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

> This bottom section is the error, i have no idea what is wants or how
> i should go about fixing the issue.
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: The error means that `wordlist` is empty. I don't see anywhere that you set it. You need `wordlist = loadWords(WORDLIST_FILENAME)`

Comment: At that point in the code, `wordlist` is not a defined variable, so this code would not even run.  Please show us your real code.